# When are generic types determined? Can it be influenced?

Tags: .net, methods, c#-2.0, generics

I've been playing around with generics and I've been seeing some weird stuff. I hope you guys have an explanation! To make everything easier I've put the "problem" into an example:

```
namespace Lab
{
    public class Animal
    {
        public Animal(string sound)
        {
            this.Sound = sound;
        }

        public string Sound { get; private set; }

        public void Kick()
        {
            Printer.Print(this, Sound);
        }
    }

    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        public Dog() : base("Bark, bark! I'll bite you!") { }
    }

    public class Printer
    {
        public static void Print<T>(T obj, string message)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("{0} says '{1}' \n", typeof(T).FullName.PadRight(10), message);
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Animal bird = new Animal("Tweet!");
            Dog dog = new Dog();

            System.Console.WriteLine("Kick bird:");
            bird.Kick();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Kick dog:");
            dog.Kick();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Print kick dog:");
            Printer.Print(dog, dog.Sound);

            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So, I have two animals in my Lab: a dog and a bird. When I "kick" those animals they'll make a sound. The printer will print the sound and the type of animal. When I run the program it prints:

> Kick bird: 
>   Lab.Animal says 'Tweet!'
>
> Kick dog: 
>   Lab.Animal says 'Bark, bark! I'll bite you!'
>
> Print kick dog: 
>   Lab.Dog    says 'Bark, bark! I'll bite you!'

Why does the first kick of the dog tell me it is of the type `Lab.Animal`? 
**And... how can I get it to return `Lab.Dog`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first kick of the dog tells you that the *compile-time type* of the type argument was Lab.Animal. In other words, your `Animal.Kick` method is effectively:

```
Printer.Print<Animal>(this, Sound);
```

Type arguments aren't determined polymorphically - they're determined at compile-time. It becomes more complicated when the type argument of one call is actually the type *parameter* of the calling context, but it's fundamentally the same kind of thing.

To make it say `Lab.Dog`, you'd have to get the actual execution-time type of the object, e.g. using

```
obj.GetType().FullName
```

Comment: My problem with GetType() is that it is pretty expensive compared to typeof(). But that is besides the point of the example. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Kees: It's "expensive" precisely because it's doing something at execution time instead of at compile-time, effectively - but you use what you need :) (Is it *really* that expensive though?)

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping the generic would give me the right type. I'm using it in my script-compiler. Basically I only need the full name of the runtime type to check if the script has already been compiled and present. GetType() provides a little bit more than the name :-).

Answer (score 3):

Normally, generics are determined at compile time, but they **are also** a runtime feature. In this case you are using generic type inference, which uses the variables etc to infer type.

In the method:

```
    public void Kick()
    {
        Printer.Print(this, Sound);
    }
```

all that is known of `this` in this context is that it must be `Animal` so there is an implicit Anmial, i.e. `Printer.Print<Animal>(this, Sound)`

Other options:

- use `GetType()` to find the actual type of the object
- use `dynamic` to defer resolution to runtime (note; not an **ideal** use of dynamic, but it works)

Comment: How are generics a runtime feature?

Comment: @Kees in .Net, they **are**; they are very unlike c++ templates, for example. In fact, you can declare a type completely at runtime, then create a `List<T>` of that at runtime; `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(someType))` etc. This is also why you can use generics from libraries without needing source or headers - it is the runtime that supports generics.